# C# Generate SSRS Reports "reportservice2005 exception"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have created a console application before that renders a report, and saves it as a pdf. I am now creating a new one following similar guidelines. When I try to run the program I get this exception:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.dll**

**Additional information: Value cannot be null.**

on this line of code:

`ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();`

I am currently using these references, which are the same as in my other console app as well:

```
using pdfGeneration.severRef;
using pdfGeneration.ssrsExRef;
using System;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

If anyone knows how to solve this or why this is happening let me know! I am a bit confused as to why it is saying this value is null..

Using visual studio 2015

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: There was an issue with the reference paths, I deleted them and reinstalled.